# Docker plugin ls returns with an error response

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

when running "Docker plugin ls" I get the following response "Error response from daemon: plugins are not supported on this platform". I have no plugins installed so i was expecting an empty list. I am running this from a windows 10 desktop os.

Answer (score 0):

[From the plugin documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/):

> **Note:** Docker Engine managed plugins are currently not supported on
>   Windows daemons.

So the error message appears to be correct, they are not supported on your platform.